# Make a transparent Dialog in android

Tags: android, xml, alpha-transparency

I have to make a transparent dialog like this image. I already try in many way like set Background `android:background="#CCFF0000"` or set background color from .java file like this

`llWhole.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`. here `llWhole` is the parent `LinearLayout` of my xml.

I also tried `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in xml file. I also tried `View.setAlpha(0.7)` .

Unfortunately none of them helped me to create this layout. Can you please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

My .xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llWhole"
    android:alpha = "0.7"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:alpha = "0.7"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Are You OK?"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="#FFF"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:alpha = "0.7"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF" >
        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOK"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:background="#F11"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNo"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="NO"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:background="#F11"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Note:

1. I am using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1`
2. My dialog is a `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`
3. My mainActivity extends `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`.     From this Activity i am showing this DialogFragment.

   `MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                       dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                               "my_transparent_dialog");`

[image]

Comment: need to see the layout for the dialog

Comment: Ok , I am updating my question

Comment: Please avoid nested layouts (bad for performances), Use a single RelariveLayout, instead.

Comment: Sir , this is my demo code only @ Frank N. Stein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue using this line of code into `onCreateView` callback.

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

I found it from [here](http://es.androids.help/q15694)

Answer (score 0):

Please try `myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Notice:
But consider using default background and be compilant with material design ui patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In you dialogFragment onCreate,try to use setStyle(,) to set a style with 
@android:color/transparent
true